# Not able to use App Generated Access Token to Upload a nuget package to github packages

Tags: github, nuget, action

Originally Posted: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/47973

Heya,

So i've been racking my brain about this for days now and I am not able to use a programmatically generated access token to upload a package to my organization's package repository.

I was able to successfully do this with a personal access token (PAT) with minimum permissions.  However when I use a GitHub App with similar permissions I am getting an 403 Forbidden Error.

Here are a few pieces of info that might be useful.

The Organization is on the "Free" account.
The App is currently configured to allow ***ever possible permission available***.  I did this to see if there was a permission I thought I was missing.
The App is installed for ALL repos on environment.  However in retrospect, we are dealing with an organization level thing, so this might get weird.

I wrote a simple powershell script that will do the work.

```
$pkg = "PACKAGE_NAME_TEST.3.0.0-beta-2.nupkg"

$apiKey = "GENERATED_APP_TOKEN" ##PAT here works fine

nuget sources add -name "testing_local" `
                  -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ORGANIZATION_NAME_HERE/index.json" `
                  -Username ORGANIZATION_NAME_HERE `
                  -Password $apiKey

nuget setApiKey $apiKey -source "testing_local"
nuget push $pkg -NonInteractive -Source "testing_local"
nuget sources remove -name "testing_local"
```

when I run the above script, I get the following results

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx\desktop> C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test package upload.ps1
Package source with Name: testing_local added successfully.
The API Key 'API_KEY' was saved for 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxx/index.json'.
Pushing xxxx.3.0.0-beta-2.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxx'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxx/
WARNING: Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
  Forbidden https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxx/ 792ms
nuget : Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
At C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test package upload.ps1:15 char:1
+ nuget push $pkg -NonInteractive -Source "testing_local"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Response status...03 (Forbidden).:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Package source with Name: testing_local removed successfully.
```

The intention is to run this via github actions, however It might also be necessary to do this programmatically through external sources.  HOWEVER,  I did at least attempt to get this to work using the `${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}`.  I still received a 403.  I believe this is because the repo is a private repo.

I ensured the github secrets token was updated to have packages write access

```yaml
name: Release Build Pipeline
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions:
  contents  : read
  packages  : write
```

403 response from Github Actions

```
Pushing Nuget files to Nuget Package Repo
Package source with Name: For_E:\gh\01\_work\amp-rewards\amp-rewards\_work\build\Deploy\EnticentAdminDashboard.3.0.0-beta-17f0dfc1641a4a608f2ead7a6e7d342f84bb8116.nupkg added successfully.
Pushing xxxx.3.0.0-beta-17f0df.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxx'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxx/
WARNING: Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
  Forbidden https://nuget.pkg.github.com/xxxx/ 30335ms
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
Push Exit Code: 1
Package source with Name: For_E:\gh\01\_work\xxxxx\xxxx\_work\build\Deploy\xxxx.3.0.0-beta-17f0df.nupkg removed successfully.
Exiting with Code: 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

At this point I am stuck using PAT which will work for now, but its not sustainable long term.

Any help in this area would be most useful.

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you find a fix?

Comment: nope, at this point it appears to be a mystery.